# Why dont we synchronise Webservices?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, synchronization, synchronous

Lets take an example of rest webservices. When we define a webservices, in the memory it is created as a singleton, but we are advised not to make the webservices synchronised? Why so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authors of the web container went out of their way to make a highly concurrent, highly scalable system that can allow as many simultaneous users as the hardware can handle.

If you go and synchronize the web service, now no matter how fast your server is or how many concurrent connections it can handle, every single users has to wait in line to use your web service one at a time.

That would be considered a pretty big architectural failure for most web services :)